# DLL dependency and HTTP module 

Tags: c#, httpmodule

I have an HTTP module in a dll, being used in a web application. I need to call a class in the web application (using a Interface defined within the dll - so we are not tightly coupled).

I define the class in the appsettings of a web.config, but cannot figure how to create an instance. I use `Type.GetType` but it just returns a null.

My app.config is

```
<add key ="ActiveClass" value ="WebApplication.Class1,WebApplication4">
```

and my Type.GetType invocation is

```
Type activeClassType = 
    Type.GetType(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ActiveClass"] as string);
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Podge

Comment: can you show what the appSetting looks like?  Did you use the AssemblyQualifiedName?

Comment: and show the code you are using tying to create the instance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to do it by using appdomain.